# Как изменить шаблон продуктов woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В шаблоне wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\content-product.php вызывается этот хук:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

Но где add_action() ???
Мне нужно изменить html шаблон продуктов

Answer (score 1):

Список хуков страницы товаров

https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/

На хук 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' по умолчанию закреплены следующие хуки

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
```

Вы можете манипулировать страницей товаров удаляю существующие подвязки к хукам через remove_action и добавляя свои хуки через add_action (свои конструкции добавлять в functions.php активного шаблона)

Шаблоны для страницы товаров woocommerce\templates\content-product.php и папка woocommerce\templates\loop\

Для изменения нужно скопировать их в тему в папку woocommerce + добавить в functions.php темы поддержку woommerce

```
add_theme_support('woocommerce' );
```

Comment: Плюсанул, но мне кажется, ему надо менять весь шаблон вывода продукта целиком.

Answer (score 0):

`add_action()` может и не быть, тогда `do_action()` ничего не делает.

Если хотите изменить шаблон, создайте папку `woocommerce` в корне дочерней темы, скопируйте в неё файл `wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\content-product.php` и правьте его.

Comment: В content-product.php как раз вызывается do_action. Значит где то вызывается add_action, которого я должен изменить

Comment: Вы не понимаете сути хуков. Ещё раз - нет у них add_action в коде. И этот do ничего не делает. Это заготовка. Вы можете у себя в теме добавить add,_action и вывести что угодно перед циклом товаров. Но это не изменит сам цикл. Как изменить вывод цикла, я написал в ответе.

Comment: do_action() в content-product.php выводит название продукта. Кроме do_action в коде ничего нет. Если убрать do_action, название пропадает. Значит где то вызывается add_action

Comment: иначе откуда взялся название продукта, если do_action сам по себе ничего не делает

Comment: Посмотрел код. Да, Valerii Vasiliev прав - на этом хуке висят две функции, которые он привёл в ответе. Одна выводит инфо о распродаже, другая - миниатюру продукта. К вашему вопросу "Мне нужно изменить html шаблон продуктов" обе отношения не имеют. Вопрос лично я понимаю так, что надо изменить весь шаблон целиком.